# Inserting variable value in line X and field X UNIX BASH

Tags: unix, sed, insert, awk, field

I have a text file with data and I want to add a value to a line and field specific place, this value comes line by line from am operation.

```
1   tamal        12341234      12457695
2   taco         234535        235796
3   enchilada    21341234      21348509
4   burger       2345345       2346789
```

Exactly what I want to do is: I want to do field 4 minus field 3 and put the result in field 5

Thanks =D

Comment: what have to you tried so far and what is the expected output?

Comment: I've thought many long ways to do it, but specifically I want to know if there is something like the $awk 'NR==<line number> {print $<field number>}' <file>  but instead for reading, for writing

Comment: You said you already have a for loop? What does that loop look like? Where is your data coming from? How are you printing it out? You can add fields with awk and sed just fine if you are already using one of them and they have the information you need.

Comment: If you have a `for` loop in shell, you are almost certainly using the wrong approach. Post what you have done so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straightforward with awk:

```
awk '{$5 = $4 - $3}1' input
```

Comment: ohh this is awesome, what is the purpose of the 1 after the } ?

Comment: +1, but the OP will probably want to set `OFS` to a tab and add a filter on NR

Comment: @Tamalero, it sets auto print so that we don't need explicit print.